# Creating a Unit Test of a Chunk Tasklet with Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, spring-batch

I have a `Chunk Tasklet` with a reader and writer, and I am trying to make a Unit Test for it, but I face multiples issues.

I used the answer of the question below, to help creating my Unit Test:
[How define a spring batch chunk in the tasklet with code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26907419/how-define-a-spring-batch-chunk-in-the-tasklet-with-code)
Its seems to be the closest to, what I want to make.

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:config/beans-unittest-service.xml",
        "classpath:config/beans-unittest-item.xml" })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class KpiMetricFromCsvFileTaskletTest extends RegistryServiceImplTest {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("kpiMetricCsvItemReader")
    ItemReader<KpiMetric> reader;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("kpiMetricCreatorWriter")
    KpiMetricCreatorWriter writer;

    @Override
    @Before
    public void init() {
        writer.setRegistryService(registryService);
        writer.setRegistry(registry);
        setCreateKpiMeasureBehaviour();
    }

    private ChunkContext createChunkContext() {
        StepExecution stepExecution = Mockito.mock(StepExecution.class);
        StepContext stepContext = Mockito.mock(StepContext.class);
        ChunkContext chunkContext = Mockito.mock(ChunkContext.class);
        JobExecution jobExecution = MetaDataInstanceFactory.createJobExecution();

        Mockito.when(chunkContext.getStepContext()).thenReturn(stepContext);
        Mockito.when(stepContext.getStepExecution()).thenReturn(stepExecution);
        Mockito.when(stepExecution.getJobExecution()).thenReturn(jobExecution);

        return chunkContext;
    }

    @Test
    public void testTasklet() throws Exception {
        StepContribution contribution = Mockito.mock(StepContribution.class);
        ChunkContext chunkContext = createChunkContext();

        Tasklet tasklet = new Tasklet() {

            @Override
            public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
                KpiMetric kpi = reader.read();
                List<KpiMetric> items = new ArrayList<>();
                while (kpi != null) {
                    items.add(kpi);
                }
                writer.write(items);
                return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
            }
        };
        tasklet.execute(contribution, chunkContext);
    }
}
```

- My Unit Test `Class` extends another `Class`, that contains methods, that will set the mock object behaviour.
- I have two configuration files. One of them contains a reader bean `kpiMetricCsvItemReader` and a writer bean `kpiMetricCreatorWriter`.
- In my Unit Test `init` method, I change the service attribute of my writer to a mock service object, I also mock the context objects, just like in the answer of the link above.

The problem is that, in the `testTasklet` method, I want to create a Tasklet and execute it, but when I run the program, I get the error:

> org.springframework.batch.item.ReaderNotOpenException: Reader must be open before it can be read.

I understand that the file is not opened, but when I launch my Job with Spring Batch, I don't get that error, so Spring should be opening my file by itself.

Now to solve this, I should either manage to open the file for the reader or delegate the creation of the tasklet to something else, that will handle it, **but how?**

---

## EDIT

Perhaps showing the reader configuration file should help :

```
    <bean id="kpiMetricCsvItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader">
        <property name="resource" value="classpath:${kpiMetricCsvFile}" />
        <property name="linesToSkip" value="1"/>
        <property name="lineMapper">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">
                <property name="lineTokenizer">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                        <property name="delimiter" value=";"/>
                        <property name="names" value="key,description,name,score,tool,variable_type" />
                    </bean>
                </property>
                <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                    <bean class="com.example.fieldmapper.KpiMetricFieldSetMapper" />
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="kpiMetricCreatorWriter" class="com.example.writer.kpi.KpiMetricCreatorWriter" >
        <property name="registry" ref="registry" />
        <property name="registryService" ref="registryService" />
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When used outside a chunk-oriented step, an item reader/writer should be opened/closed manually. So in your case, you need to open the reader yourself before using it to read data.

You can refer to the unit test of the [FlatFileItemReader](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/item/file/FlatFileItemReaderTests.java#L97-L104) itself as an example.

Comment: Ok, I get my problem, I use the ItemWriter interface, but my writer is actually a FlatFileItemReader as you can see in the spring configuration file, I will just change it in my Class.
I'll see if its work tomorrow, (it probably will) thanks for the help.

Comment: I made a mistake, in my previous comment, I meant ItemReader instead of ItemWriter and reader instead of writer